# Creating Oracle procedure for selecting recently added data to CLIENT table and if found then add those records to Archive table

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have a table CLIENT and i need to filter it so it shows only recently added records.

```
SELECT *
FROM Client
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= sysdate -1;
```

I have to create PL/SQL procedure that inserts those records into Archive table with Newest='y'. Newest is a column in archive table. And remove Newest='y' from old records which are already in archive table.

I am stuck in here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_to_arch(
arch_ archive%rowtype )
as
begin

SELECT *
FROM Client
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= sysdate -1;



loop
INSERT
INTO archive
(
CLIENT_ID,
  NAME,
  SURNAME,
  PHONE,
  VEH_ID,
  REG_NO,
  MADE_MODEL,
  MAKE_YEAR,
  WD_ID,
  WORK_DESC,
  INV_ID,
  INV_SERIES,
  INV_NUM,
  INV_DATE,
  INV_PRICE
)
SELECT CL_ID,
CL_NAME,
CL_SURNAME,
CL_PHONE,
VEH_ID,
VEH_REG_NO,
VEH_MODEL,
VEH_MAKE_YEAR,
WD_ID,
WORK_DESC,
INV_ID,
INV_SERIES,
INV_NUM,
INV_DATE,
INV_PRICE
FROM CLIENT, INVOICE, VEHICLE, WORKS, WORKS_DONE
 WHERE CL_ID = arch_.Client_ID;
 end loop;    
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

put the "SELECT * FROM Client WHERE TIMESTAMP >= sysdate -1;" into a cursor, like:

```
CURSOR cr_c IS
SELECT *
FROM Client
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= sysdate -1;
```

Then iterate through cr_c in a FOR loop
(http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php)

OR

use trigger, maybe that would be better
(http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php)

Comment: Okay that i understand but i am not sure how to write this business logic when i need to transfer them to Archive table with column Newest saying 'y'. I have to do this in procedure not trigger!

Comment: @Mairis You are trying reinvent the wheel. Search in web how to store historical data. If someone else try change table not through your procedure then old data willn't apper in historical table.

Answer (score 0):

how about just a merge statement.  merge into archive using the client table. match on the ids.  if you find a record in the archive table then just update the newest indicator to 'N'. if you don't find a record in the archive table then insert the record with 'Y' as the newest value.  don't have your data so you will probably have to play with the statement below but something like this.

```
MERGE INTO archive a USING
(SELECT client_id col_a, col_b, col_c FROM Client
) c ON (a.client_id = c.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET a.newest= 'N' WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (
      a.client_id,
      a.newest,
      col_a,
      col_b,
      col_c
    )
    VALUES
    (
      c.id,
      'Y',
      c.col_a,
      c.col_b,
      c.col_c
    );
```

Comment: i was asked to do it in procedure because that procedure needs to be automatically once a day

Comment: because it would go to fast otherwise?  just put begin end around it and bam you got your procedure

Comment: Okay i did it, but procedure dublicated my records instead of 2 records i got now 24

Comment: Well yes, if you copy all rows for the past 24 hours then you have to do this every 24 hours precisely, otherwise you risk either duplicating or missing rows. Or add some more logic to exclude rows you have already copied that have not changed, or do it in a trigger etc.

Comment: what should i do now then?